# Multiple level shortcodes

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I am working on a plugin and stopped in a situation, I hopesomeone can help me with a solution.

I want to have a shortcode structure like :

```
[shortcode_1]
[shortcode_2]
[shortcode_3]
[shortcode_4][/shortcode_4]
[/shortcode_3]
[/shortcode_2]
[/shortcode_1]
```

But if I use add_shortcode, only first shortcode works...

Is there any way to have a shortcode structure like this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [Nested Shortcodes in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes)?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the content of each shortcode through `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );` - you may not be getting your shortcode output because it's never being called in the first place (beyond the top level). `the_content` filter include `do_shortcode()` (from memory), which is what you need. See how it goes...